# MonoTouch AdHoc Distribution - The application was terminated by a signal: SIGIOT

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm revisiting some MonoTouch code that I wrote a few months ago and haven't touched since then. This is was working fine and is deployed to the App Store.  When I open it now and try to Run it in Distribution|iPhone mode, I get the error "The application was terminated by a signal: SIGIOT".  The other thing that I noticed is that under Properties->iPhone Build, my SDK version was set to "3.2 (not installed)".  I switched this to 4.2 (the only other choice), but it dind't help. (There are no spaces in any of my paths)

Does anybody have any suggestion on what to look for to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you can post the whole error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

Have you tried cleaning your solution and rebuilding everything again? MonoDevelop might simply be trying to run an already compiled version of the app.

You might be trying to deploy the app to an iphone using a certificate that is expired. In that case, go to iTunes connect and get a new one.

Comment: I did try cleaning the solution (multiple times).  I also checked the expiration dates of the certificates in XCode.  None of them expire for another three months.  The app builds and installs just fine in Debug or Release mode, just not Distribution.

Comment: oh, you're trying to run the distribution build? You can't do that. The signature that apple provides you to send the build to their appstore doesn't allow you to run the executable in a phone. Only after they resign it that it runs.. Hopefully that's it.

Comment: Oh geez...this is what I get for leaving iOS development for a couple of months.  That makes sense, thanks.